# How to get the name of the argument in a function in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, function, arguments

I have a script with a function like this:

```
lion = 'Roar'
cat = 'Kitty'

def dosomething (a, b):
   directory = a.getargv()
   file = open('%s/%s.txt' %(directory, a), 'w')
   file.write(a + 'is not' + b)
   file.close()

dosomething (lion, cat)
```

In place of a.getargv (that of course it doesen't exist) I want to get the name, and not the value, of the argument of the function (in this case the word 'lion'), there are some way?

I solved adding another parameter that I called *name*, that is a string with the value *'lion'* (in this case), but I'm trying to understand if there are another solution:

```
lion = 'Roar'
cat = 'Kitty'

def dosomething (a, b, name):
   file = open('%s/%s.txt' %(name, a), 'w')
   file.write(a + 'is not' + b)
   file.close()

dosomething (lion, cat, 'lion')
```

Comment: the lion you are passing is the value. Its not the parameter of the name

Comment: using kwargs will be helpful for you

Comment: Refer this http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv/

Comment: @suraj this is for Command Line Arguments, not for function arguments

Comment: @ArpitSolanki kwargs is useful only if the arguments are in the form _dosomething(lion='Roar', cat='Kitty')_.
It creates something like a dictionary where the key is the name of the variable and the value is the assigned value of the variable.